# How to divide each number of two list with each other?

Tags: python

> Hi I'm sorry if the question is really basic, I'm new into this and I did my research but I only found the solution using import but I want to learn another way.

```
   List1 = [1,2] 
   List2 = [3,4]
   Expected Output = [1/3, 1/4, 3/1, 4/1, 2/3, 2/4, 4/2, 3/2]
```

Comment: 2 for-loops to divide everything both ways

Comment: You can use `itertools.product`

Comment: A list comprehension would do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
c = []
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        c.append(f"{i}/{j} = {i/j}")
        c.append(f"{j}/{i} = {j/i}")
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a nested loop with the two lists for taking an element of the first divided by an element of the second, then another nested loop for the second divided by the first, then you concatenate both results:

```
d = [ x/y for x in List1 for y in List2 ] + [ y/x for x in List1 for y in List2 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using nested loops.

```
list1 = [1,2] 
list2 = [3,4]
new = []
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        new.append(round(x/y,2))
for a in list2:
    for b in list1:
        new.append(round(a/b,2))
```

list comprehension

```
list1 = [1,2] 
list2 = [3,4]
new = [i for i in [[round(x/y,2) for y in list2 for x in list1]+[round(a/b,2) for a in list2 for b in list1]]][0]
```

output

```
[0.33, 0.25, 0.67, 0.5, 3.0, 1.5, 4.0, 2.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try list comprehension:

```
List1 = [1,2] 
List2 = [3,4]

List3 = [x/y for x,y in zip(List1,List2)] + [y/x for x,y in zip(List1,List2)]
```

This will give you your desired result.

Comment: zipping `List1` and `List2` won't generate the "cross-products", it will only pair 1 with 3 and 2 with 4, but not 1 with 4 and 2 with 3... So zipping does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```py
from itertools import product
output=[x/y for x,y in product(List1, List2)] + [x/y for x,y in product(List2, List1)]
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
[0.3333333333333333, 0.25, 0.6666666666666666, 0.5, 3.0, 1.5, 4.0, 2.0]
```

You can tweak it a bit to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I Try my best but i am not able to make in proper format like sting but in float you can do like this:

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [3,4]
list3 = []
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    for j in range(0, len(list2)):
        list3 += [list1[i]/list2[j]]
        list3 += [list2[i] / list1[j]]
print(list3)
```

output is:
[0.3333333333333333, 3.0, 0.25, 1.5, 0.6666666666666666, 4.0, 0.5, 2.0]